# What is the easiest way convert line endings to unix style when creating tar file in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, newline

At work we use a mixture of Windows and Linux workstations during development.  For deployment we always deploy to Unix machines.  I'd like to ensure that the line endings are always in Unix format.  What is the easiest way in Gradle to achieve this?  I was thinking it might be possible to use a FilterReader but I didn't manage to find a ready made one.  Would this be the best option?

Comment: Line endings of what? Content of your resource files?

Comment: Configuration files in this particular case in a tar file I'm creating.  I found something that seems to work for me and posted it below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Editing this entry to use a Copy task instead.  Initial version of this was using a Tar task but I noticed that while it was stripping the CRLF when run in Linux but on Windows it was failing to work correctly.  Since they're both copyspecs AFAIK I would have expected Tar tasks to work the same but sadly this is not the case (gradle 1.0-milestone-3).*

Looks like I've figured it out myself.  The FilterReader required is FixCrLfFilter.  The following snippet shows how you might use it:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.*;

task archiveit(type: Copy) {
  from "conf"
  into "targetdir"
  filter(FixCrLfFilter.class,
         eol:FixCrLfFilter.CrLf.newInstance("lf"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution for Gradle 7.5.1 and JDK 8 is to set `line.separator`.
You can add below lines to your build.gradle file.

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n")
task dos2unix(type: Copy) {
  from $sourceFile
  into $targetFile
  filter { line -> line }
}
```

[Neeme Praks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74694/neeme-praks) solution is not working, because gradle filter is using LineFilter class. And LineFilter.readTransformedLine method adds line separator for every line.

Answer (score -1):

The answer by Glen did not work for me, so I came up with even simpler solution:

```
task archiveit(type: Copy) {
  from "conf"
  into "targetdir"
  filter { line -> line.replaceAll('\r\n', '\n') }
}
```

Should work with all tasks that support filters, including `Tar` task.

Comment: Does not work for me. I think the "line" does not have its ending anymore. Testedwith Gradle 6.1.1